# How to play 70 differents short sound on one HTML page

Tags: html, audio, icons

### For a learning course I want people to click on a speaker icon. No pause nor volume necessairy.
Finally I came up with this, it works but it is ugly. I only want the loudspeaker icon.
Anybody the solution - in my solution with an icon it returns only one sound in spite of the different url I give.

Een "**v**" en een "**o**" van 'p**o**p'
    
----------------------------------------
Thanks a million for helping me out.
Aristos

See the details above - I hope I posed my programming problem clearly there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.